# Can you repeal a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

There have been several questions of mine here on this site that have been voted by users to be closed. The majority of them I understand the reasoning to why they were closed but a few I don't agree with. Do I have the ability to repeal a closed question and thus re-open or edit it?

Comment: Not sure if any of your questions have been deleted, but I only saw four closed questions. The only one that's _maybe_ worthy of reopening IMO is this one: http://superuser.com/questions/481178/is-it-more-cost-efficient-to-keep-my-computer-on-and-allow-it-to-go-into-s4-hibe As such I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks @Tanner for the input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the way to go. You can always edit your questions into better shape. Per our FAQ:

> Closed questions cannot be answered, but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through editing, voting, and commenting.

Closed questions that are edited will be bumped to the front page (unless their score is too low). On higher traffic sites, reopen votes by users with 3k reputation may trickle in naturally then, but on Super User this *often* isn't the case, so your edit might go unnoticed.

I'd suggest to choose one of these approaches. Make sure you mention what you did to improve the question.

- post a [reopen-request](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request) here on Meta, which gives you the chance of more input by the community
- flag the question for moderator attention to have it reviewed